# How to erase, clear, wipe HTML 5 localstorage for a web app saved to home screen on an iPad?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, local-storage

There is a fine summary of how localstorage works in iOS 6 here:

http://blog.nsbasic.com/2012/09/important-io6-and-data-storage/

Many seem to be concerned by the fact that safari and web apps do not share localstorage etc.. However, I can't seem to find the answer to the question in the title *anywhere*:

My situation: I am developing a HTML5 web app with web-app-capable and want it to be able to run from the home screen. Everything seems to work fine, but for development, I need to be able to clear the cache once in a while. I have tried everything I could think of (and any thinkable combination and sequence of them...):

1. Clear Safari Cache
2. Delete app from home and reload it
3. Reload the web page over and over before saving it to home
4. Clearing the cache (`localStorage.clear()`) from within the app

What are your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to clear the localStorage.

```
localStorage.clear()
```

You can add counter to be stored in localStorage and do something like this.

onload:

```
 localStorage.reloadCount = localStorage.reloadCount || 0
  //make sure its not undefined
 localStorage.reloadCount = localStorage.reloadCount*1;
  // it stores in string values
 if(localStorage.reloadCount>4)
    localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: Thanks Gena. This is what I meant by "4. Clearing the cache (localstorage) from within the app". Doesn't work, unfortunately, on my iPad 2, iOS 6.0. That's why I asked the question...